# iText Architecture Design using Sonargraph Architect

Tags: architecture, itext, evaluation

I'm doing a research in Software Architecture Evaluation field and currently I'm trying to evaluate iText library using Sonargraph Architect. I chose iText because it's an open source and java-based project (Sonargraph Architect still only support java-based application at this time).
I've tried to search for any clear architecture description of iText but still have no luck. I'm still a newbie in Software Architecture field and it's still quite hard for me to define the architecture by myself just by looking at the source code structure.
Does anyone have any reference / insight about the iText architecture?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is off-topic on SO.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a specific iText problem, but about its architecture in general.

Comment: Bruno : I'm so sorry that it's my very first time asking on SO. Is there any other forum that is more relevant to my question? I really need an enlightenment about this.

Comment: I'm the original developer of iText. I have a degree in architecture (civil engineering, I know how to draw buildings), but I don't have a degree in computer science. Hence I do not know the language you expect to hear if you'd ask me to describe the architecture. You are probably better placed to describe the architecture of the code I originally designed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. I think I have known what to do now.

Comment: I forwarded the question to our SonarQube guy. He'll start experimenting with Sonargraph soon.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Lowagie. I'm looking forward to knowing further updates from you. Meanwhile, I'm experimenting iText with Sonargraph as well.

Comment: And if it's ok for you, I would like to have your email contact to have further discussions about this. I've just got a notification from SO to avoid extended discussions in comments like this. Or, an opened discussion thread in another forum would be ok too.

Comment: SO doesn't approve sharing mail addresses in posts or comments, but you shouldn't have any problem finding an itextpdf.com address to contact us ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I have checked itextpdf.com and I found sales contact and mailing list to all iText user (which I have subscribed to it). Which one is appropriate for you to have further discussion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iText is a nice and helpful tool handling all things around PDF. It really works but when it comes to (software) architecture from my experience there is none. Have a look at the iText source code to see for yourself.

I didn't know about Bruno's background however that (partially) proves it. This is (really!) no offense - I implemented and structured things way different before studying computer sience / software engineering. When you have a computer science related degree part of the studies is the development of a good software architecture and the overall structuring of source code etc. How can you make it easy for new developers to understand the code, do changes etc.

If I would try to do an architects work (for real buildings, constructions etc.) - my buildings would probably colapse ;-) . That is part of the reason why people spend studying many years to really learn a profession.

I am curios what your findings will be - please sure you post them here. This may help to further improve the software and the overall architectural quality of the project.

Comment: IMO it is not so much a matter of the original developers background but of the age of the current API and the changes it went through. With such a history, many an API goes unstructured. It simply is time (actually has been time for quite a long while now) to completely re-think and overhaul the API. This is not easy, though, as already the overhaul of the signature mini-sub-API has shown.

Comment: Agreed. And of course time (as in the age of the project) also plays an important role - if there is no architectural rethinking, restructuring and refactoring - there will be uncontrolled growth...

Comment: Yes, I agree that iText is a very powerful PDF library and I've used it in some of my projects. I have spent days since the first time I posted this topic to go through the source code. Yes, all things inside are totally unstructured and it is really a lot of work to analyze how things should be grouped together, how it should be separated, and all many other architectural considerations.

Comment: What I am trying to do now is monitoring all the communication calls from the JUnit Tests and try to analyze all the communication logs, which reaches more than a hundred giga. It will take quite some time until the final result but I believe we are on the right path. Sure, it's my main motivation to contribute for the further improvement of this software. I know many projects have relied on iText and it's still a growing project. So, an action to refactor the architecture is really needed soon before it's getting bigger and bigger.

Answer (score 0):

QA Engineer at iText Software here. I don't have a high enough reputation at this particular part of SO yet to be able to comment, so I'll do it in an answer.

I was not yet familiar with Sonargraph Architect, so I downloaded an evaluation version. The first thing that happened, was a JVM crash when I loaded iText into Sonargraph Architect. I have been in contact with hello2morrow support, and they have confirmed the issue. They will fix it in their Sonargraph 7.2 release which is planned for this month (September 2014).

As far as I understand it, these are the products from hello2morrow:

- Sonargraph-Explorer: code metrics
- Sonargraph-Architect: architecture definition -> this is what you are using, and what crashed for me.
- Sonargraph-Quality: in-depth analysis of technical quality. -> I may evaluate this tool at a later time.
- Sonargraph-Sonar integration -> this is what I am currently evaluating for our own build process

I will add on this answer when I get a new release from hello2morrow or when I have any other relevant findings.

Comment: Thank you for your response and concern regarding this question. I have a research license for Sonargraph Architect and I have tried to import your code in http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/HEAD/tree/ without any problem. Is it the newest one?

Comment: Yes. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and my current JVM is `1.8.0_20-b26` (Oracle), but I'm going to try again with OpenJDK 7.
EDIT: nope, also crashes with OpenJDK 7.

Comment: I'm using windows 8.1 and my JVM version is 1.8.0_11-b12 (Oracle). I imported iText project to Sonargraph without any problem. Btw, I have sent you an email (which I got from Mr. Lowagie) and maybe we can have further discussion via email rather than commenting on SO? Thanks.